# Can't open Windows Terminal with Windows + R, while it opens fine from a command prompt

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, shortcuts

When I press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and type `wt` or `wt.exe`, it gets stuck loading for a few seconds and then stops, failing to open my Windows Terminal.

How can I solve this or find a short workaround? I don't want to write the full path, but e.g. a 10-letter command would be fine.

#### What I've tried

- Loading the full path and it successfully opens.
- Running as admin, and the admin prompt appears, but it fails to open.
- Openning <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, inserting the command, but it also fails.
- When I first open `cmd.exe` and then try to launch `wt` from there it works just fine and Windows Terminal opens in under 2 seconds.
- Running  C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.11.3471.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\wt.exe fails

I'm running on Windows 11 with the 1.11.3471.0 version of the normal Terminal, not the preview one.

Comment: Windows + S and then type wt should work.

Comment: @Robert I tried, but the command doesn't work, still

Comment: Can you try running the `wt` or `wt.exe` command from a command prompt? So, press Win+R, type `cmd` and in that prompt type `wt`. I am curious if any error or message shows in the command prompt.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke it works just fine, and very fast, it takes around 2 seconds to start

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate if your running Windows 10 or Windows 11. You should also indicate what version of Windows Terminal your running.

Comment: I don't have Windows 11, but if you want a workaround you could pin the Windows Terminal icon to the taskbar. Now it's just one click away, or (at least in Windows 10) if you pin the icon on position 2 in the taskbar, pressing Win + 2 opens it.

Comment: Did you by chance take ownership of the WindowsApp directory?

Comment: Additionally, make sure wt.exe is enabled in App Execution Alias

Comment: On my system I just installed Windows Terminal, the alias was enabled by default and running wt.exe from the run command worked.  I disabled it, and it failed, so make sure the alias is enabled. Running Windows Terminal as an Administrator is more involved then you might think.

Comment: @Ramhound Alias is available

Comment: Think I found the cause of the problem, when I try to run C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.11.3471.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\wt.exe it fails

Comment: It fails when you try to run it from the Run window? But it works when you try to launch it from cmd.exe? Or if you double click wt.exe in Explorer? Or does that all fail? I ask because you mentioned in the first point "*Loading the full path and it successfully opens.*", so I am confused which "*full path*" you were referring to there.

Comment: @MiguelFernández - It should fail because you don't have permissions to that directory by default.  Hence the reason I asked if you changed the permissions on the WindowsApps directory.  So Have you?  *That is the purpose of the Alias.*

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke it fails on run window and C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.11.3471.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\wt.exe. However it works in all other situations, like the path C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe or C:\Users\migfe\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal1.11.3471.0_x64_8wekyb3d8bbwe\wt.exe

Comment: @Ramhound so the reason it fails is because of the permissions I changed? Is there a way to return them to default?

Comment: @MiguelFernández - Reset Windows 11; Changing the permissions on WindowsApps is known to break UWP applications (or whatever is their current name)

Comment: @Ramhound ok, thank you, then

Comment: It’s not that I don’t want to help you, I just don’t know, how exactly you broke it

Comment: @Ramhound I know, it was just frustration from my part of not being able to solve it. I meant it, thank you for the help :)

Comment: New info: I decided to execute icacls /reset. I tried in several folders, which led to being able to open the wt on run windows, but some things failed in the way. When wt opens from run window and when I execute `wt` on `cmd`, windows cannot find wt.exe. However, on normal boot, this error doesn't appear, it runs as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had changed permissions in the WindowsApps folder, therefore it failed.

However, I found in https://winaero.com/reset-ntfs-permissions-windows-10/ the way to return them to default: in cmd as administrator, insert `icacls "full path to the folder" /reset /t /c /l`, quotation marks for the path are necessary. I executed this for `"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps"` and for `"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps"`, I think, but I'm not sure whether it ended here, Microsoft or Local.

It's up to you, which one you decide to execute, the only downside is time spent, since the shorter paths have more folders to change.

`icalcs /reset` replaces permissions of the folder to the default ones.
`/t` is for all files and folders below;
`/c` avoids stopping if error occurs;
`/l` follows a link if needed.

I also had to make some changes, because I messed up, like deleting the Windows Terminal folders, but I don't think they are important.