# Run Window can't open wt

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, shortcuts, windows-terminal

A couple days ago I reinstalled windows and ever since, I can't open the Windows Terminal through the run window.

**I tried:**
Changing permissions to default, following this question [Can't open Windows Terminal with Windows + R, while it opens fine from a command prompt](https://superuser.com/q/1701713/1552968)

**What works:**
Running from the cmd powershell, wsl... Creating a shortcut off wt.exe.

**What doesn't work:**
Executing `wt` on run window or [Win]+[S]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound said: `Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.WindowsTerminal | Reset-AppxPackage`. Running it from the powershell as admin solved it

Answer (score 0):

Open Windows Store and type "Windows Terminal"  (without the quotes) and either Get it or Install It.

I just did this on one machine and Windows Terminal worked perfectly after that.

This was the easiest way.

You can also use Power Shell:

get-appxpackage Microsoft.WindowsTerminal -allusers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}

Comment: The user is running Windows 11.  Windows 11 is already present on their machine.

Comment: I used the Store Install as I suggested in Windows 11 and it worked just fine.

Comment: I would recommend the Reset command instead of reinstall it. So the command would be `Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.WindowsTerminal | Reset-AppxPackage`. @John - I meant to say that Windows Terminal would already be present on Windows 11. Worth pointing out that author modified the permissions on WindowsApps, I suspect their problems, are directly connected to that fact. They were unable to provide specifics to how they modified the permissions on the directory.

Comment: @Ramhound It sounds like you are referring to some information that isn't present in the question itself.  Was there a discussion in the comments?  What happened to it?  It sounds like there was useful additional information there -- Such as the Windows version, for starters.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds - The author linked to their previous question. Our very long discussion lead to, figuring out, what happened but now how and I explained it was entirely expected to be broken.

Comment: @Ramhound Ah - I didn't realize that the linked question was from the OP.  Thanks!

Comment: @Ramhound you are a genius, I don't know how, but you are always right. That command solved it. Thanks

Comment: @MiguelFernández - Solved it a year ago, no problem